# What is Facades and how it works? (Specially for Laravel)

Tags: laravel-5, facade

Can you please describe elaborately about **Facade**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Facade is an alias to classes that are available in the application's service container, these classes can be Laravelor vendor package classes. Facades are used because they provide a terse, memorable syntax that allows us to use Laravel/Vendor features without remembering long class names.

In short Facades allow you to use fro example JWTAuth::getToken(), instead of having to type out  Tymon\JWTAuth::getToken() in full, increasing code readability.

[read More][1][1]: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/facades

Comment: So, a Facade simplifies the interaction with several Classes. Without calling several classes to get access of the services of the container, it helps to jump and catch that services/methods from the container class. Thanks. May be I am so far clear now.