# Adding Facades before namespace in Laravel , How it works?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-facade

Okay there are questions about the same topic before but they don't help to fully understand this topic

[SO SuggestionFirst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642068/what-is-facades-and-how-it-works-specially-for-laravel)

[SO Suggestion Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642068/what-is-facades-and-how-it-works-specially-for-laravel)

All the code is just to illustrate the situation, So this is the structure
A helper function which does something

```
namespace App\Helpers;

class Pets{

    public function limit($string,$limit,$start = 0){
        return substr($string,$start,$limit);
    }
}
```

Now in order to use this helper, since it's a class so i need to create an object like this

**CODE SAMPLE FIRST**

```
namespace App\Objects;

use App\Helpers\Pets;

class User{

    public function getShortUserName(){
        $name = auth()->user()->first_name.' '.auth()->user()->last_name;
        $pet = new Pets;
        return $pet->limit($name,10);
    }
}
```

But somewhere I got to know that if you add **Facades** before your namespace, you can call the function statically even if they are non static function like this

**CODE SAMPLE SECOND**

```
namespace App\Objects;

use Facades\App\Helpers\Pets;

class User{

    public function getShortUserName(){
        $name = auth()->user()->first_name.' '.auth()->user()->last_name;
        return Pets::limit($name,10);
    }
}
```

Now what I want to know is I have 2 sample codes with namespace as follows

```
use App\Helpers\Pets;
use Facades\App\Helpers\Pets;
```

By adding the Facades I can call the function statically but how, that's not a valida namespace in my app
What laravel doing behind the scene, I am so confused

Thank you for your time ;)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/facades

Comment: Documentation don't have anything related to that, i have already checked it

Comment: @BlackXero try autoload for helper https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is Laravels Real-Time Facades.

You can find documentation of the functionality here:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/facades#real-time-facades

Answer (score 0):

I will not enter too much in details but this is a simple explanation of what's behind the scenes when you use facades in laravel.

Let's suppose you define a custom class with some public methods:

```
namespace Test;

class Foo
{
    public function test()
    {
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

Then you have to define a facade for this class:

```
namespace Test1;

class BarFacade
{
    // In laravel this is called in the Facade abstract class but it is actually implemented
    // by all the facades you add across the application
    public static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        // In laravel you can also return a string which means that the object 
        // will be retrieved from the container.

        return new \Test\Foo();
    }

    // In laravel this method is defined in the Facade abstract class
    public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        $object = self::getFacadeAccessor();

        return call_user_func_array([$object, $method], $args);
    }
}
```

Then, you have to define the alias in the `$aliases` array of the `config.app` file. These aliases are parsed by laravel and registered using the php built-in function [class_alias](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php) (see Illuminate/Foundation/AliasLoader.php)

```
class_alias('Test\Foo', 'BarFacade', true);
// You can also create an alias for the facade itself
class_alias('Test1\BarFacade', 'FooBar', true);
```

Then you can simply call the facades:\

```
var_dump(BarFacade::test());
var_dump(\Test1\BarFacade::test());
var_dump(\FooBar::test());
```

The results would obviously be:

```
string(4) "test"
string(4) "test"
string(4) "test"
```

Comment: You said, We need to define a Facade for our class, But in my case I have not defined any facades for my class and yet I can access the function, anything ?